# publish a function in Matlab using custom 'FileName'

Tags: matlab, publish, rename

I'm running `publish` function in Matlab in a loop.  Is there a way to *customize* the output filename?

Eg., publish runs TopFunction which itself prints out Fun1, Fun2.  You can see that *TopFunction.html* is overwritten each time (along with images etc).

I'm trying to see if I can customize the output name? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky, but I would modify `publish` to accept a new option `prefix`. Replace line 93

```
[scriptDir,prefix] = fileparts(fullPathToScript);
```

with

```
if ~isfield(options, 'prefix')
    [scriptDir,prefix] = fileparts(fullPathToScript);
else
    [scriptDir,~] = fileparts(fullPathToScript);
    prefix = options.prefix;
end
```

Now you can set `options.prefix` to whatever filename you want. If you want to be really hardcore, make the appropriate modifications to `supplyDefaultOptions` and `checkOptionFields` as well.

Answer (score 0):

rename the file with the matlab 'movefile' function within a loop